# Rails button_to tag is not rendering at all during the loop statement

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

Here's my code below.

```
<%@allemployeeleaveapplications.each do |each_employee_leave_application|%>
  <div class="table_row 1" onclick="showHide('divHidden1');" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div class="left_expand_collapse" style="margin-right:6px;">
      +
    </div>
    <div class="table_column_no_margin" style="width: 10%;">
      <%=each_employee_leave_application.staffname%>
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 10%;">
      <%=each_employee_leave_application.leavetypedescription%>
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 10%;">
      <%=each_employee_leave_application.totaldaystaken%> Days
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 10%;">
      <%=calculateRemainingLeaveEntitlements(each_employee_leave_application)%> Days
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 10%;">
      <%=number_to_currency(each_employee_leave_application.totaldaystaken * 7.5 * each_employee_leave_application.calculatedratesamount, :precision=>2)%>
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 100px;">
      <%=each_employee_leave_application.startdate%>
    </div>
    <div class="table_column" style="width: 46px;">
      <%=each_employee_leave_application.enddate%>
    </div>
    <% if each_employee_leave_application.applicationstatusid ==3 %>
      <div class="table_column" style="width: 184px; display:inline-flex;margin-left:40px;">
        &nbsp;
        <div style="float:left;">
          <%= button_to 'Approve', { :action=>"update_leave_entitlement_status", 
:leave_entitlement_type_id=>each_employee_leave_application.leave_entitlement_type_id, 
:employee_id=>each_employee_leave_application.employee_id, :status_id=>"1"},style: 'background-color: #6EBA66;width: 88px; height:22px; margin-right: 4px; padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:22px; cursor:pointer', 
method: :post, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure you want to approve this staff leave application?' } %>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;">
          <input type="button" name="Reject" value="Reject" style="background-color: #D70D1E;width: 88px; height:22px;padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:22px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div class="table_column" style="width: 50px;">
        <%=each_employee_leave_application.applicationstatusname%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Basically what I'm saying is that I have an array of all employee leave applications and I'm looping each of the items inside employeeleaveapplications and render its individual field data such as their entiltlement type, username, start date of leave application, end date of leave application etc.  And I placed a button tag to create a submit button for the manager to approve/reject these staff leave entitlements.

Whilst the code logic is fine, I encountered some bizzare behaviours when viewsing my app under Google Chrome.  This is what I found for a staff leave entitlement that's not yet approved or rejected.

```
<div style="float:left;">
  <div>
    <input data-confirm="Are you sure you want to approve this staff leave application?" 
style="background-color: #6EBA66;width: 88px; height:22px; margin-right: 4px; padding-top:3px;padding-bottom:22px; cursor:pointer" 
type="submit" value="Approve">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="fN4Vb/PvtALrAE7TtzAb3Hp/cJEpbkvF22sE1Pttt6I=">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is totally incorrect when I'm expecting to see the form tag above the input tag comment, along with the details of my custom controller/action/parameters in one line.  But it's not rendering that tag as I originally wanted it.

How can a simple code setup could suddenly become totally senseless when it's not rendering the form tag fields as it should be?  I mean the form tag fields do appear in the browser at times - but not all the times! It ended up in this state!  I dont' really understand why that's the case?

Can someone out there shed some light on this and tell me where did I, possibly, do wrong with my code.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I found out where the problem lies.

It was because I had another extra  tag lying around in my html code somewhere, which interferes the rendering for the buttom forms above!

All sorted now.